# Understanding routing from client side (javascript) to server side (node.js)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, routes

I'm new at web apps and at the moment I'm trying to wrap my head around routing from client side to server side and back. I ran in to a problem where I was doing xmlhttprequest on my client side to get a json, which was working. But now that im not running locally none of the GETS are working. So I figured I have to do routing to server side, do the request() to get the json, which I can.

But now what I don't understand is how to pass that json back to client side to use the function there, since all my functions that use this json are there. Is this possible? or do I have to do everything server side now?

server side

```
server.get('thankyou.html/something', function(req, res) {

    var options = {
        url: 'https://**.***.**.**:****/****/*******/',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,   
        method: 'GET'
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        else displaytable(body);//<------- clientside funtion
    });
});
```

client side

```
var uri = 'thankyou.html/something';

function addTable() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 201 || xhr.status == 200)) {
           // var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            displaytable(json);
        }

    };
    xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

I think I'm not doing the routing right either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the expected flow here? client -> your server @ thankyou.html/something -> some other server url (the one you have censored) -> response back to your server -> response back to client -> client uses response to display table?

Either way, you definitely can't call client functions from your server. Not like that, anyways. You'll need to return the `body` with something like `res.json(body)` (what routing / server library are you using?), and then parse the `xhr.responseText`, like your commented-out line was doing. Then you'll have the json on the client, and can continue as expected.

Make sure if your `request` call returns an error that you pass the error through to the client as well, or it will hang until timeout.

Comment: that's exactly what im trying to do. I dont thing im using any routing libraries, but im pretty sure you mean if im using express library right? I think i understand the process you're explaining.

Comment: Yup, if you were using `express` was what I needed to know. When you use express, you can call `res.json(object)` to return the object to the client response as json, which can then be parsed like you were considering. That is the "correct" way to do what you want (assuming the body from `request(options...` contains the data you're looking for on the client, anyways).

Comment: I think my uri value i have on client side is incorrect. How do i know what to use there?

Comment: Oh that depends on how you expose your server. Express will typically have something like `server.listen(8080)` where the `8080` will be the port. So, using that as an example, and assuming your development server is on your local ip `127.0.0.1`, you would use `var uri = "127.0.0.1:8080/thankyou.html/something;`. And at this point you can probably see that you'll need some way to make the urls different when you're developing compared to when you publish it to a server with a non-local IP. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: If your server is also serving the client files, you can *technically* bypass the need for the explicit IP and use relative routes, too. But I'm not sure if that's the case. And personally, I prefer splitting up the servers which provide client files / html, and the ones that handle API style calls (which is what this looks like). But relative urls may technically be an option available to you, as well.

Comment: thats pretty much what my uri was, guess i still got alot of learning to do! Thank you @dvlsg